# Proof: Integral in between two bounds

Tags: integration

Claim: $ 2/\sqrt{6} \ge \int^1_0 \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1+x}}dx \le 1/3 $.

What is the process to prove this? I can't come up with a proof;

I am thinking Squeeze theorem would be useful here maybe, but I'm not sure how and if it can be applied to integrals. Or if there is a better way to do it?

Comment: you can evaluate this integral as 0.2532 without too much trouble.

Comment: Please don't change the question. People have taken the time to answer the first question; now their answers don't relate to the new question. If you have another problem, post another question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How

$1\leq\sqrt{1+x}\leq\sqrt{2}$ in $[0, 1]$

$1\geq\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}}\geq\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. How $x^2>0$ imply

$x^2\geq\dfrac{x^2}{\sqrt{1+x}}\geq\dfrac{x^2}{\sqrt{2}}$

Integrate

$$\int_0^1x^2dx\geq\int_0^1\dfrac{x^2}{\sqrt{1+x}}dx\geq\int_0^1\dfrac{x^2}{\sqrt{2}}dx$$

$$\dfrac{1}{3}\geq\int_0^1\dfrac{x^2}{\sqrt{1+x}}dx\geq\dfrac{1}{3\sqrt{2}}=\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{6}.$$

Answer (score 3):

**hint**: $\sqrt{2} \geq \sqrt{1+x} \geq 1$

Comment: Thank you! I think I am just confused on the way to think about this; what is the proof technique?

Comment: Try subtituting the bounds in for $\sqrt{1+x}$ in the integral.